# List of lists to matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list of lists and I want to convert it into a matrix such that each column = one sublist.

**Mock example**

```
list1 <- list(1, 2)
list2 <- list(1, 2, 3)
list3 <- list(1, 2, 3, 4)

list_lists <- list (list1, list2, list3)
```

I'm first egalizing the lengths of all the sublists (padding with NULLs if needed) so that all sublists have the length of the longest one. That is to avoid having R repeating data to fill in the rows in the final matrix (feel free if I can skip this step somehow).

```
max_length <- max(unlist(lapply (list_lists, FUN = length)))
list_lists <- lapply (list_lists, function (x) {length (x) <- max_length; return (x)})
```

**My best attempt so far**

```
mat <- lapply (list_lists, cbind)
```

`mat` does look superficially like what I want but it is actually not. It is not a matrix (and attempts to convert it into one using `as.matrix` are unsuccessful) and I cannot refer to columns/rows like I would do with a matrix.

**I am expecting**

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 1    1    1   
[2,] 2    2    2   
[3,] NULL 3    3   
[4,] NULL NULL 4
```

What is weird to me is that

```
mat <- cbind (list_lists[[1]], list_lists[[2]], list_lists[[3]])
```

seems to work. I would bet these two lines are the same, how can they be different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sapply instead of lappy like this:

```
list_lists <- sapply (list_lists, function (x) {length (x) <- max_length; return (x)})
```

this should give you the matrix that you wanted. Seems like the sapply will recursively unlist each list in the list_lists then apply the function that you specified and wrap all the outputs into a matrix, effectively bypassing the other line that you specifie above.

Answer (score 11):

They are different, **lapply** returns a list, See below from an excerpt from documentation

Use `do.call` instead of `mat <- lapply (list_lists, cbind)` as following:

```
mat <- do.call("cbind",list_lists)
```

`do.call` is same as `cbind (list_lists[[1]], list_lists[[2]], list_lists[[3]])` , it happens to operate on a sequence of lists which would be dataframe columns.

```
> do.call("cbind",list_lists)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 1    1    1   
[2,] 2    2    2   
[3,] NULL 3    3   
[4,] NULL NULL 4   
>
```

Understanding do.call:

**From documentation:**

> **do.call** constructs and executes a function call from a name or a
>   function and a list of arguments to be passed to it.
>
> **lapply** returns a list of the same length as X, each element of which
>   is the result of applying FUN to the corresponding element of X.

Search on r console for `?do.call` and `?lapply`

You can also read: [do.call](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html) and [lapply](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `stri_list2matrix` function should be able to handle this:

```
library(stringi)
stri_list2matrix(list_lists)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,] "1"  "1"  "1" 
## [2,] "2"  "2"  "2" 
## [3,] NA   "3"  "3" 
## [4,] NA   NA   "4"
```

Another option is to use your "max_length" to create the matrix:

```
ml <- max(lengths(list_lists))
do.call(cbind, lapply(list_lists, function(x) `length<-`(unlist(x), ml)))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    1    1
## [2,]    2    2    2
## [3,]   NA    3    3
## [4,]   NA   NA    4
```

A third option is to use `melt` from "reshape2":

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(list_lists), L2 ~ L1)
##   L2  1  2 3
## 1  1  1  1 1
## 2  2  2  2 2
## 3  3 NA  3 3
## 4  4 NA NA 4
```